# rendering one item from a list in Ember

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app, I get a list of all the restaurants using an ajax call copied from Discourse co-founder's blog post http://eviltrout.com/2013/02/27/adding-to-discourse-part-1.html

```
App.Restaurant.reopenClass({

  findAll: function() {

     return $.getJSON("restaurants").then(
      function(response) {
        var links = Em.A();
        response.restaurants.map(function (attrs) {
          links.pushObject(App.Restaurant.create(attrs));
        });
        return links;
      }
    );
   },
```

I have a Restaurants route set up which calls the findAll shown above and renders it into the application template

```
App.RestaurantsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function(params) {
    return(App.Restaurant.findAll(params));

  },

  renderTemplate: function() {

    this.render('restaurants', {into: 'application'});
  }

});
```

The restaurants are displayed as a `restaurants` template like this with a link to each individual restaurant. I've also included the `restaurant` template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="restaurants">

  <div class='span4'>
      {{#each item in model}}
      <li> {{#link-to 'restaurant' item}}
      {{ item.name }} 
      {{/link-to }}</li>
    {{/each}}

         </ul>
     </div>

  <div class="span4 offset4">
   {{ outlet}}
   </div>

</script>
```

In the Ember router, I have a parent/child route set up like this

```
 this.resource("restaurants", function(){
         this.resource("restaurant", { path: ':restaurant_id'});

     });
```

Therefore, I'm hoping that when I click on the link to a particular restaurant in the restaurants list, it'll insert this `restaurant` template into the `outlet` defined in the `restaurantS` (plural) template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="restaurant">
         this text is getting rendered
      {{ item }} //item nor item.name are getting rendered         
</script>
```

This restaurant template is getting rendered, however, the data for the `item` is not getting displayed.

When I click `{{#link-to 'restaurant' item}}` in the list, `item` represents that restaurant.

In this setup, does Ember need to make another ajax call to retrieve that particular item, even though it's already been loaded from the `findAll` call?

In the event that I do need to query for the individual restaurant (again) I created a new route for the individual restaurant

```
App.RestaurantRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log(params);
    console.log('resto');
    return App.Restaurant.findItem(params);
  }

});
```

and a findItem on the Restaurant model

```
App.Restaurant.reopenClass({

findItem: function(){
    console.log('is this getting called? No...');
    return 'blah'
  }
```

but none of those console.logs are getting called.

In the Ember starter video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QHrlFlaXdI, when Tom Dale clicks on a blog post from the list, the post appears in the template defined for it without him having to do anything more than set up the routes (as I did) and the {{outlet}} within the posts template to receive the post.

Can you see why the same is not working for me in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you navigate to the `restaurant` route, the `item` will be the `model` to this route.

So in your template, if you try

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="restaurant">  
     this text is getting rendered  
  {{ model.name }}      
  </script>
```

You'll be able to see the name of the restaurant

And also the model hook is not called, and the further `console.log`s are not working,
because

> Note: A route with a dynamic segment will only have its model hook called when it is entered via the URL. If the route is entered through a transition (e.g. when using the link-to Handlebars helper), then a model context is already provided and the hook is not executed. Routes without dynamic segments will always execute the model hook.

Hope everything will  be clear now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had no idea what the problem was as Ember wasn't throwing any kind of error message. I wonder why it wouldn't tell me there's no `item` in the template